# Error retreiving audio with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

So here it is, I want to loaded audio from a 3rd party web service end point as opposed to an audio file, and I also want it to appear as a link instead of the audio player, so I included the following code in my HTML file:

```
<a href="#" onclick="var audio = document.createElement('audio'); audio.src='https://example.com/grabaudio'; audio.type='audio/mpeg'; audio.play();">Audio</a>
```

**The above code works when I click the link to play the audio**

But the problem lies in when I want to dynamically generate similar elements on my page to play audio.  If I were to load up a blank web page, paste the code (same endpoint that normally works if on the page when originally rendered), and click the link, no audio would play and a 404 page not found error is logged in the console.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the audio can be retrieved if the code is on the originally rendered html document but not if it is added dynamically?  It's my understanding that the request being sent to the endpoint should be the same regardless of when the code that generates the request was created.

Comment: `paste the code` - paste what code where?

Comment: Using the browser developer tools

Comment: I didn't ask "how" I asked "what" and "where"

Comment: Inside the body tag

Comment: right, so you paste that HTML (the `<a>` tag, that's in the question) inside the BODY tag ... right ... exactly that HTML as it appears in your question ...

Comment: So It looks like this:
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="var audio = document.createElement('audio'); audio.src='https://example.com/grabaudio'; audio.type='audio/mpeg'; audio.play();">Audio</a>
</body>

Comment: exactly ... but example.com doesn't have a page called grabaudio, hence the 404 error

Comment: example.com is commonly used as a placeholder for an actual website. trust me when i say the actual link i'm using points to an endpoint that exists

Comment: I know, but I did ask `exactly that HTML as it appears in your question`